# TeX capacity exceeded + Semantics package

Tags: math-mode, errors, semantics

I get the following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\do #1#2#3->\mathcode `#1
                     ="8000
l.14 ..._{1}\; a_{2} -> v_{2}}{a_{1} - a_{2} -> v}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on samlet.log.
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

It happened after I started using the semantics package: http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/semantic/semantic.pdf

The document that makes it not compile can be seen here:
http://pastebin.com/ycJ6taKw

If I compile with only one of math blocks it will compile just fine, and yes the document is the input to a master .tex file.

Comment: The presented code is not enough. We have to guess the document class etc. Please post an MWE that we can copy'n'paste and *use as is*, then it is much more likely that you are going to get help.

Comment: Alright, here's the non working version:
http://pastebin.com/ACqfczY4

Here's the working version:
http://pastebin.com/rBFSw7Hd

Answer (score 0):

That is hardly minimal, here is a more relevant minimal example (and I will not even start to complain about the structure in the original)

The problem seem to come from the `-` in the second example. Perhaps a problem from the `->` syntax, tough I have (yet) not found anything about it in the manual.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{semantic}

\begin{document}

This works 
\[
\mathlig{-><-}{\rightarrow\leftarrow}
\inference[Plus]{a_{1} -> v_{1}\; a_{2} -> v_{2} }{a_{1}+a_{2} ->
  v} \; Where\; v = v_{1} + v_{2}
\]

this does not
\[
\mathlig{-><-}{\rightarrow\leftarrow}
 \inference[Plus]{
   a_{1} -> v_{1}\; 
   a_{2} -> v_{2}
 }{
   a_{1} - a_{2} -> v
 }
 \; 
 Where
 \; 
 v = v_{1} -  v_{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

Update: Actually if you remove the `\mathlig{-><-}{\rightarrow\leftarrow}` it compiles just fine, and the `->` still give the arrow. So my guess is there is something odd going on in `\mathlig`.